# Is it possible to open an ethernet connection in a web worker?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, web-worker

I'm using a web worker in an Electron/NodeJS application and want to know if it's possible to create an ethernet connection inside of one? I saw you can create a serial connection using the WorkerNavigator, but don't see anything about ethernet. I know web workers are kinda limited in what they can do but thought I'd ask anyways

Comment: What do you mean by "ethernet connection", exactly? An ethernet connection is a physical cable you physically plug into a physical socket on your computer...

Comment: @Dai I guess like open a socket to an IP via a port, like you would with NodeJS's "net" package

Comment: In short: **no**, there is no way in web-browsers to create TCP, UDP, or IP connections - nor or transmit/receive data except via WebSockets, WebRTC, or `fetch`/`XMLHttpRequest`.